# comparison between innerText and a variable not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-scraping, nightmare

I am using nightmare.js to web scrape I'm trying to add an id to a button by getting a value that was received by an input and adding the id to a button if the text inside the button matches the input.

```js
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: false })
const rp = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

var size = "9";

nightmare
  .goto('https://www.flightclub.com/')
  .type('#search', 'air jordan 1 shadow \u000d')
  .wait(1000)
  .click('.result-thumbnail')
  .evaluate(() => {
    var correctSize = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    for (var i = 0; i < correctSize.length; i++) {
      if (correctSize[i].innerText.trim() === size) correctSize[i].id = 'thisone';
    }
  })
  .click('button[id=thisone]')
  .end()
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Search failed:', error)
  })
```

This doesn't work properly, but if size is replaced with just "9" inside the comparison then it works properly. Is there any other way around this and is there a reason why we can't compare innerText to a variable?

Comment: What are you passing in `input`? Can you create a snippet of your code? That would be easy to debug?

Comment: Are you sure `input` is defined in the scope and is what you expect? Clearly this code is incomplete so wherever the problem is, it's in whatever is missing.

Comment: what is `correctSize`? Should it be `button[i].innerText.trim()`? It will be great if you make a snippet.

Comment: I just added the full code, hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This test `correctSize[i].innerText.trim() === input` is checking string values.

When you pass in an `input` type the value will not match. You should use `input.innerText` or similar so you are comparing the correct values.